# How to direct my site to the proper URL without Dashboard

Tags: database, htaccess, dashboard, user-access

While messing around in the settings on the Dashboard, I changed the address of the site into a subdomain of the site. This means that WordPress forwards all links to a subdomain (ex: `web.site/home` redirects to `web.site/home/home`).

Because the dashboard itself is on a subdomain in WordPress it also gets redirected to an unknown address.

I've read online that I need to edit my `.htaccess` file to redirect to the right place, but so far I haven't been able to fix it.

I've got a feeling the fix is somewhere in the database files of the site, but I can't find a way to access them without the WordPress Dashboard functioning.

Does anyone here have more knowledge about the workings of WordPress and where I can fix this?

Comment: Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Fixing this through the database is the best way to regain access to your Dashboard. Since it sounds like that you only changed the site URL and nothing else, do the following:

1. In your database (via phpMyAdmin) go to the `wp_options` table and you'll find the `site` and `home` rows
   [image: Site & Home URL]
2. You should see `http://web.site/home/home` in either one or both fields, change it back to your original URL `http:web.site/home/`

You should now be able to access your *Dashboard* again.